# DataTables, export datatable to CSV file where column values have commas

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm using datatable in my laravel app, with 2 columns (id, address) wanted to export contents to a csv file.  However some of the values in the address column have commas in them.  So, when the user open the csv file the value is split into columns.  For example the datatable looks like this:

id, address
1, Chicago, IL

however, when user opens csv file in excel:
A, B, C
id, desc
1, Chicago, IL

So the value: "Chicago, IL" gets split into 2 columns, B and C when opening in excel.
I was expecting only excel columns A and B (id, address) to be populated.

Is there something that I can do to escape the comma or format the cell so that when the user opens the file there are only 2 columns populated and the address column has the value:
Chicago, IL

I tried to find the solution everywhere but no luck so please this question is not duplicated
Thanks in advance.

```
<table class="table" id="sample_1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="all export"> id </th>
<th class="all export">address</th>
</tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
 @foreach ($data as $item) 
 <tr>                                  
 <td >{{ $item->id}} </td>
 <td >{{ $item->address}} </td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>

   TableDatatablesEditable = function() {
    var e = function() {
        var e = $("#sample_1"),
            t = e.dataTable({
                dom: "Bfrtip",
                buttons: [{
                    extend: "print",

                    className: "btn dark btn-outline"
                }, {
                    extend: "pdf",
                    className: "btn green btn-outline"
                }, {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
               exportOptions: {
                     columns: ['.export'],
                              },
               className: "btn-outline"
                }],
                language: {
                    lengthMenu: " _MENU_ records"
                },
                columnDefs: [{
                    orderable: !0,
                    targets: [0]
                }, {
                    searchable: !0,
                    targets: [0]
                }],
                order: [
                    [1, "desc"]
                ],
                lengthMenu: [
                    [5, 10, 15, 20, -1],
                    [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"]
                ],
                pageLength: 20,
                dom: "<'row' <'col-md-12'B>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>"
            });
```

Comment: I tried to find the solution the same but didn't found i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you can print the value in quotes inside the table. The text inside quotes won't break into columns by Excell.

Ex

```
<td >"{{ $item->id}}"</td>
```

Comment: DK thank you this is working fine but how can I ignore the "" in the view?

Comment: That is done already through the `fieldBoundary` option, which by defailt is `"`. The above will result in `""column data""` ...But not a bad idea though :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs -> https://datatables.net/reference/button/csvHtml5

You could force the delimiter to be a semicolon `;` instead of `,`

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'csvHtml5',
    fieldSeparator: ';'
    //..other options
  }],
})
```

Comment: @Ash No, obviously the CSV just need to be imported to LibreOffice, Excel or whatever with `;` as separator.  I know for a fact that Excel 2016 and beyond detect the `;` automatically, older versions come with an import dialog where you can specify separator, delimiter, charset etc before importing the CSV. So does LibreOffice as well.  You *can* do all sort of manipulation with the content, like converting commas to unicode or similar, but the superior best and recommendable is to style the CSV correct so it fits the content, not to fit the content so it is adjusted to a specific CSV layout.